# Obtain port number to which a server is listening to?

Tags: linux, port

I am interfacing MATLAB with COMSOL, a scientific software that servers as my computation server here.

After I start COMSOL, it starts to port 2036 by default. If the port is busy, it listens to port 2037 and so on. Then, in MATLAB, I have to specify the port number so that MATLAB can connect itself to COSMOL.

The problem is the school HPC is shared, meaning I cannot always get port 2036. What's worse, I do not actually know to which port COMSOL is currently listening to. COMSOL does not provide a solution to this.

So I hope there is a generic method on the shell/linux level whereby I can get the port number that is being listened to by COMSOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ps -ef | grep <process_name>` to find the process id of your COMSOL application.  Then, run:

```
netstat -anp | grep -w <process_id>
```

This will show all the ports that are being used by that process, and you will be able to see what ports it's listening to.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But can we further make it require no human intelligence? I need to do batch jobs. So it is barely possible for me to "find the process id". Thanks!

Comment: @FarticlePilter it might be possible to use `lsof` to do this in a batch format, but I'm not sure how to automate it.

Answer (score 1):

I like John's answer the best, but what about something horrible like:

```
for portnumber=2036:3000
     try
         mphstart(portnumber);
         break
     catch
         fprintf('\n continue');
     end
 end
```

Comment: This is when starting matlab normal, as in not clicking on the Comsol with Matlab by the way.